# Returning database results as an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
$a=array(
    'last' => array('Ford', 'Smith', 'Jones', 'Thomas'),
    'first' => array('Joe', 'Kyle', 'Nick'),
    );
```

I have all these names in my database, and a couple more like age, etc.

How can I pull all the records from the database and set them as a array for $a? I need them to be in the format above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

```
$query = "SELECT last, first from names"; //whatever the query is...
$results = mysql_query($query);
$all = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
   foreach($row as $key=>$value){
       if(!isset($all[$key])) $all[$key] = array();
       $all[$key][] = $value;
   }
}
```

The results would look something like:

```
$all=array(
    'last' => array('Ford', 'Smith', 'Jones', 'Thomas'),
    'first' => array('Joe', 'Kyle', 'Nick','Allen'),
...
    );
```

Comment: When the opportunity presents itself, please try to promote `MySQLi` or `PDO:MySQL` instead of the outdated `mysql` library.

Comment: But I don't know how many there will be for $all, what if there's 20 different ones, and new ones that are generated, how would you check for them instead of having them pre-defined as an array?

Comment: @joseph , im not sure i understand ur question, but ill try

Comment: Basically for $all you have 'last' and 'first' set. Those are in a table along with say 20 different terms; i.e. age, location, etc.

Comment: Thanks Neal, greatly appreciated, although I am rather confused. So now $a would be $all[$key][] = $value?

Comment: I'm just confused on how I would get the data (Ford, Smith, Jones, Thomas) for say 'last' now that's it's coming from the database. Which variable is that assigned to?

Comment: @joseph updated above. it would have the same result as you wanted. also on stack overflow. you have to choose a correct answer, if you do that to ur questions, more people would want to help u with future questions ^_^

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thanks for the explanation, and I have voted your answer as the 'accepted answer'. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry one more thing, I forgot to mention the values for 'last', 'first', and all others are in one table column separated by commas. Example: last = ford, smith, jones, thomas. At what point would you explode() this?

Comment: lol dont do that. otherwise: `$split = explode(',', $row['value'])` then explode each of the splits by `=`

Answer (score 0):

Just to post the obvious...the codeigniter active record application of @Neal's answer would look like this:

```
$this->db->select('first,last,age');
    $query = $this->db->get('my_table');
    $results = $query->results();
    if($query->num_rows() > 0 ){
        foreach($results as $result as $key=>$value){
            $all[$key][] = $value;
        }
```

I omitted the check because I typically do that in the view.